# Magento 2.2.x How to get recently view product collection programmatically?

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.2

Here is code but not getting collection

```
namespace [Vendor]\RecentlyViewed\Block\Customer;

use \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context;
use \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility;
use \Magento\Customer\Model\Session as CustomerSession;
use \Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Viewed;
use \Magento\Reports\Model\Product\Index\Factory as IndexFactory;

class RecentlyViewed extends Viewed
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    private $customerSession;


    /**
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility
     * @param \Magento\Reports\Model\Product\Index\Factory $indexFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct
    (
        CustomerSession $customerSession,
        Context $context,
        Visibility $productVisibility,
        IndexFactory $indexFactory,
        array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $productVisibility, $indexFactory, $data);
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }


    /**
     * @return \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Index\Collection\AbstractCollection
     */
    public function getRecentlyViewedProducts()
    {
        $collection = $this->getItemsCollection();
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($collection->getData());
    exit;
        return $collection;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to load the collection.

```
$this->getItemsCollection()->load();
```

There is a note here: `$this->getItemsCollection()` doesn't load the collection. But:

1) Foreach the collection items will load the collection

**\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection::getIterator()**

```
public function getIterator()
{
    $this->load();
    return new \ArrayIterator($this->_items);
}
```

2) Count the collection items will load the collection as well: `$this->getItemsCollection()->count()`.

**\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection::count()**

```
public function count()
{
    $this->load();
    return count($this->_items);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I checked it but not getting products.

Comment: Maybe cache issue?

Comment: no, I cleared cache already.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution.

```
namespace Test\Viewproduct\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

/**
 * Main contact form block
 */
class Viewproduct extends Template{

    protected $_recentlyViewed; 
    protected $_productloader;
    protected $storeManager;  
     /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */

    public function __construct(Template\Context $context,
         \Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Viewed $recentlyViewed,
         \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productloader,
         \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
         array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_recentlyViewed = $recentlyViewed;
        $this->_productloader = $productloader;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    } 
    public function getMostRecentlyViewed()
    {
        return  $this->_recentlyViewed->getItemsCollection();
    }
    public function getProductById($id)
    {
        return $this->_productloader->create()->load($id);

    }
    public function getMediaUrl()
    {
        $currentStore = $this->storeManager->getStore();
        $mediaUrl = $currentStore->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
        return $mediaUrl;
    }
}
```

phtml

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 0;" class="owl-button-top above-padding below-padding block widget block-new-products grid">
        <div class="page-title-main">
            <strong role="heading" aria-level="2">Recently View Product</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="block-content">
            <!-- new_products_content_widget_grid-->
            <div class="products-grid grid">
            <div class="slider-outer owl-carousel">
              <ol style="margin-bottom: 0px; " class="product-widget-slider products list items product-items widget-new-grid owl-carousel owl-theme">
              <?php foreach ($viewProduct as $value)  {
                 $p_id=$value->getProductId();
                  $items=$block->getProductById($p_id);

               ?> 
              <div class="owl-item" >
          <li class="product-item product-slider" style="display: list-item;">
                                  <div class="product-item-info">
                                      <div class="product-img-main">
                                            <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $items->getProductUrl(); ?>" class="product-item-photo">

                  <span class="product-image-container" style="width:350px;">
                        <span class="product-image-wrapper" style="padding-bottom: 127.42857142857%;">
                          <img class="product-image-photo" src="<?php echo $media.'catalog/product'.$items->getImage();?>" alt="Reprehenrit voluptate " height="446" width="350">
                    </span>
                    </span>
                                            </a>
                                            <div class="product-item-inner">
                                                        <div class="product actions product-item-actions">
                                                <div class="actions-secondary" data-role="add-to-links">
                                                            <a href="#" data-post='<?php  echo $this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data')->getAddParams($items); ?>' class="action towishlist" data-action="add-to-wishlist"
                                                              title="Add to Wish List"
                                                            ><span>' .__('Add to Wish List') . '</span></a>


                                                            <?php $compareHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare'); ?>
                                                        <a href="#" class="action tocompare"
                                                           data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $compareHelper->getPostDataParams($items); ?>'
                                                           title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Compare') ?>">
                                                            <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Compare') ?></span>
                                                        </a>

                                                  </div>
                                            </div>
          </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="product-item-details">
                                    <strong class="product-item-name">
                                        <a title="Reprehenrit voluptate " href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $items->getProductUrl(); ?>" class="product-item-link">
                                               <?php echo $items->getName(); ?>                                         </a>
                                    </strong>
                                    <div class="price-box price-final_price" data-role="priceBox" data-product-id="10">
                <span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee">
                        <span id="old-price-10-widget-new-grid" data-price-amount="169" data-price-type="finalPrice" class="price-wrapper ">
                      <span class="price"><?php echo $items->getPrice(); ?></span>
                    </span>
                      </span>
                </div>
                                <div class="product-item-inner">
                                            <div class="product-item-actions">
                                               <div class="actions-primary">
                                               <?php if ($items->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($items); ?>

                        <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['action']; ?>" method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['product']; ?>">
                            <input type="hidden" name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED; ?>" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED]; ?>">
                            <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
                            <?php $storeManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface'); ?>
                                <button type="submit"
                                        title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')); ?>"
                                        class="action tocart primary">
                                    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                </button>
                        </form>
                        <?php else: ?>
                                <?php if ($items->getIsSalable()): ?>
                                                                <div class="stock available"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('In stock') ?></span></div>
                                                            <?php else: ?>
                                                                <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Out of stock') ?></span></div>
                                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                                                <?php endif; ?>

                    </div>
                                        </div>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
      </li>
      </div>
      <?php }?>

              </ol>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method it will definatly run... and enjoy

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Viewed $recentlyViewed,
    array $data = []
){
    $this->recentlyViewed = $recentlyViewed;
} 
public function getMostRecentlyViewed()
{
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$recentlyViewedClass = \Magento\Reports\Model\Product\Index\Viewed::class;
$recentlyViewedProductCollection = $objectManager->create($recentlyViewedClass)->getCollection();
$recentlyViewedProductCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                                ->setPageSize(5) // load 10 products
                                ->load();

if($recentlyViewedProductCollection->getSize() > 0 )   {
 
    $product['message'] = "";
    foreach($recentlyViewedProductCollection as $item) {
        $data[]= $item->getData();
        $product['data'] = $data;
    }
    echo json_encode($product);
    die;
}
```

}
}